# npm package seems to be corrupted

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli, npm-package, npm-version

I am getting these warnings and then errors at the end. What is the fix?

```
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.10: core-js@<3.0 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.9: One of your dependencies needs to upgrade to fsevents v2: 1) Proper nodejs v10+ support 2) No more fetching binaries from AWS, smaller package size
npm WARN tarball tarball data for @angular/compiler@^8.0.0 (sha512-ABZO4E7eeFA1QyJ2trDezxeQM5ZFa1dXw1Mpl/+1vuXDKNjJgNyWYwKp/NwRkLmrsuV0yv4UDCDe4kJOGbPKnw==) seems to be corrupted. Trying one more time.
npm WARN tarball tarball data for @angular/core@^8.0.0 (sha512-zeePkigi+hPh3rN7yoNENG/YUBUsIvUXdxx+AZq+QPaFeKEA2FBSrKn36ojHFrdJUjKzl0lPMEiGC2b6a6bo6g==) seems to be corrupted. Trying one more time.
```

Comment: use npm update  command

Comment: isn't it possible that you have a cached version of it which is corrupted? try npm cache verify and then npm install/update

Comment: I did npm cache verify, npm update and npm install but getting same warnings.

Comment: Remove angular globally and re-do an npm install -g @angular/cli

Comment: i am also getting the same error while creating new project in Ionic. Did npm cache clean, npm update, uninstall and install ionic, cordova. still same... Please let me know where these dependencies versions are listed. I mean the path of the json file where the npm is installing these component. Please help..

Comment: @Dip Please show package.json file

Comment: Same issue for me as well

Answer (score 13):

Try removing `package-lock.json` and then `npm install`. This worked for me:

```
cd <your-project-directory>
rm package-lock.json
npm install
```

Answer (score 6):

1. Remove **package-lock.json**
2. Remove **node_modules**,
3. and then install packages using `npm install`.

This resolved issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

You need to disable your antivirus software and run cmd as an administrator. Don't forget disabling the windows firewall.
As for the deprecated Core-js 2.6.10 I'm facing the exact same issue but at least it's a warning you can ignore. I've tried reinstalling Angular cli and manually updating Core-js to the latest version using `npm install -g core-js@latest` unfortunately neither worked.
Also fsevents seems to be Mac related and nothing to worry about.

Comment: That seemd to by me case too.

Answer (score -1):

You need to confirm whether the Typescript is installed and after installing typescript it worked for me

running the below comment will show the typescript version

```
tsc -v
```

If it shows some error install the typescript

```
npm install -g typescript
```

If then typescript is installed you can try checking the Angular Cli version

```
ng --version
```

If it shows some error then install Angular Cli
Ref: https://cli.angular.io/

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Answer (score -1):

I had to reinstall node.js to fix this.

I had to uncheck the box for auto install chocolatey

Answer (score -1):

Changed the integrity to a relevant one, then it worked upon triggering the jenkins build. The hash updated was given in jenkins console logs.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Maybe there is a language barrier, but your answer is not clear. Can you elaborate more?